How do I pass the Task Token to an EC2 run-instances call from AWS Step Functions
How do I pass $$.Task.Token to an EC2 run-instances call from AWS Step Functions?
Should I pass it using "user-data" key in the json request?
It becomes more difficult since user-data key accepts ONLY base64 encoded string. The string $$.Task.Token is passed as it is and not its value.
Or is there any other way to pass the task token to an aws EC2 instance?
